# SQL : Can WHERE clause increase a SELECT DISTINCT query's speed?

Tags: sql, performance

So here's the specific situation: I have primary unique indexed keys set to each entry in the database, but each  row has a **secondID** referring to an attribute of the entry, and as such, the **secondIDs** are not unique. There is also another attribute of these rows, let's call it **isTitle**, which is **NULL** by default, but each group of entries with the same **secondID** have at least one entry with 1 **isTitle** value.

Considering the conditions above, would a **WHERE** clause increase the processing speed of the query or not? See the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT secondID FROM table;
```

vs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT secondID FROM table WHERE isTitle = 1;
```

EDIT:

The first query without the WHERE clause is faster, but could someone explain me why? Algorithmically the process should be faster with having only one 'if' in the cycle, no?

Comment: Seems like something you can easily test yourself

Comment: Different queries, different result. Why compare?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, true, my mistake, I was just hoping for an answer with an explanation.

Comment: @jarlh sorry if my explanation was not clear, but different queries, same result. The question was the speed, and the reason behind it.

Comment: To make the query faster, I'd try indexing on `secondID`, and with the second version of query, a partial index `ON secondID WHERE isTitle=1`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Different products have different optimization tricks.

Comment: Also, data distribution, statistics, etc. matters.

Comment: I'd say, without the WHERE clause can in best case be marginally faster, but in most cases probably slower. A WHERE clause, and a proper index, will be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, to benchmark performances of queries, you usually use queries that gives you the execution plan the query they receive in input (Every small step that the engine is performing to solve your request).

You are not mentioning your database engine (e.g. PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL), but for example in PostgreSQL the query is the following:

`EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT secondID FROM table WHERE isTitle = 1;`

Going back to your question, since the `isTitle` is not indexed, I think the first action the engine will do is a full scan of the table to check that attribute and then perform the SELECT hence, in my opinion, the first query:

`SELECT DISTINCT secondID FROM table;`

will be faster.
If you want to optimize it, you can create an index on `isTitle` column. In such scenario, the query with the WHERE clause will become faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very hard question to answer, particularly without specifying the database.  Here are three important considerations:

- Will the database engine use the index on `secondID` for `select distinct`?  Any decent database optimizer should, but that doesn't mean that all do.
- How wide is the table relative to the index?  That is, is scanning the index really that much faster than scanning the table?
- What is the ratio of `isTitle = 1` to all rows with the same value of `secondId`?

For the first query, there are essentially two ways to process the query:

1. Scan the index, taking each unique value as it comes.
2. Scan the table, sort or hash the table, and choose the unique values.

If it is not obvious, (1) is much faster than (2), except perhaps in trivial cases where there are a small number of rows.

For the second query, the only real option is:

- Scan the table, filter out the non-matching values, sort or hash the table, and choose the unique values.

The key issues here are how much data needs to be scanned and how much is filtered out.  It is even possible -- if you had, say, zillions of rows per `secondaryId`, no additional columns, and small number of values -- that this might be comparable or slightly faster than (1) above.  There is a little overhead for scanning an index and sorting a small amount of data is often quite fast.

And, this method is almost certainly faster than (2).

As mentioned in the comments, you should test the queries on your system with your data (use a reasonable amount of data!).  Or, update the table statistics and learn to read execution plans.